# What is 'xAlexaTest' Extension in my Browser

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, firefox, extension

Recently I have noticing this Extension in all of my browser including Chrome, MS Edge, Firefox. I removed it several times but it coming back each time I remove it. I have deleted all the file in 'C:\ProgramData\Ykpu\Fbsbn\E7FC424' but no result. How can I remove this extension form computer for good ?
I also like to mention that my google account was compromised couple of those days ago. I can't surely say that was this one responsible for that or not.
I have added a screenshot bellow.

[image]

Comment: Looks like an unpacked extension to test Alexia.  Alexia is the name of the Amazon voice assistant.  You probably have third-party software reinstalling it.  This has little to do with your compromised Google Account given that Firefox and Edge are not connected.  It’s also possible it’s the toolbar [here](https://www.alexa.com/toolbar).

Comment: @Ramhound how can I identify the third-party software !  If you look at the screenshot, it says this extension loaded from 'C:\ProgramData\Ykpu\Fbsbn\E7FC424' . I have delated 'Ykpu' folder but it is also restored automatically few moment later. and I also want to know why this extension is on all of my browsers !

Comment: Only you can determine what’s on your system at this point.  The installation directory certainly isn’t normal but I don’t use unpack extensions